# DynamoDB usable for largeish event table?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm thinking of re-architecting an RDS model to a DynamoDB one and it appears mostly to be working using a single-table design. We have, however a log table that can contain 5-10 million rows that are queried on many attributes.

Is there any pattern that might be applicable in migrating to DynamoDB or is this a case where full scans would be required and we would just be better off keeping the log stuff as a relational table?

Thanks in advance,
Nik

Comment: Usable? Yes. Should you? Who knows. But rearchitecting RDS to Dynamo requires a full shift in mindset and actually starts from the application as opposed to the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Those keywords and phrases "log" and "queried on many attributes" sound to me like DynamoDB is not the best solution for your log data. If the number of distinct queries is fairly limited and well-known in advance, you might be able to design your keys to fit your access patterns.

For example, if you commonly query on Color and Quantity attributes, you could design a key like `COLOR#Red#QTY#25`. And you could use secondary or global secondary indexes for queries involving other attributes similarly.

But it is not a great solution if you have many attributes that you need to query arbitrarily.

**Alternative Solution:** Another serverless option to consider is storing your log data in S3 and using Athena to query it using SQL.

You will likely be trading away a bit of latency and speed by taking this approach compared to RDS and DynamoDB. But queries against log data often don't need millisecond response times, so it can cover a lot of use cases.

Answer (score 0):

### Data modelling for DynamoDB

1. Write down all of your access patterns, in order of priority/most used
2. Research models which are similar to your use-case
3. Download NoSQL Workbench and create test models where you can visualize your ideas
4. Run commands against DynamoDB Local and test your access patterns are fulfilled.

---

#### Access Parterns

Your access patterns will ultimately decide if DynamoDB will suit your needs. If you need to query based on multiple fields you can have up to 20 Global Secondary Indexes which will give you some flexibility, but usually if you exceed 8-10 indexes then DynamoDB may not be a good choice or the schema is badly designed.

Use smart designs with sort-key and index-key overloading, it will allow you to group the data better and make your access patterns more efficient.

---

#### Log Data Use-case

Storing log data is a pretty common use-case for DynamoDB and many many AWS customers use it for that sole purpose. But I can't over emphasize the importance of understanding your access patterns and working backwards from those to create your model.

---

#### Alternatives

If you require query capability or free text search ability, then you could use DynamoDB integrations with OpenSearch (via Lambda/EventBridge) for example, with OpenSearch providing you the flexibility for your queries.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like a good use case - I have done it and wasn't at all happy with the result - now I load 'log like' data into elasticsearch and much happier with  the result.

In my case, I insert the data to dynamodb - to archive it - but also feed data in ES, but once in a while if I kill my ES cluster, I can reload all or some of the data from ddb.